# Using Python to create a Hotkey that enters text

Tags: python, hotkeys

I followed some other tutorials and was able to create an application that prints "Detected HotKey" when ever Shift+P is entered on a keyboard. Below is the .py code that I was using. It only prints the text in the command window that opens when i run the .exe. I was hoping to be able to get something that enters the text at my cursors position. I am using python 3.7

For example I would like the hotkey Shift+P to be able to enter text when I am chatting in Discord, Slack, or Gmail. Is this possible? or is there a better way to do something like this?

```
from pynput import keyboard

COMBINATIONS = [
        {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char="p")},
        {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char="P")}
        ]

current = set()

def execute():
    print("Dectected HotKey")

def on_press(key):
    if any ([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.add(key)
        if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
            execute()

def on_release(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.remove(key)

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: This looks like something that can only run when the script has keyboard focus. I imagine it would take a bit more work to steal keystrokes at a higher level.

Comment: It registers when I press Shitf+P in Gmail, Discord, and Slack. I can see my text string being entered into the command prompt for the .exe. I just do not know how to get it to pass to the other applications. I assume it is possible though.

Comment: I was able to get this to work using Pyautogui

Answer (score 0):

This is a minor modification that does what you want, took me about 2 minutes of reading `pynput` documentation:

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

kbd = Controller()

COMBINATIONS = [
        {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char="p")},
        {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char="P")}
        ]

current = set()

def execute():
    print("Dectected HotKey") #goes into the console window

    #"hitting" backspace to remove the "P",
    #must be unnecessary if we use some other modifier (Alt, Ctrl)
    kbd.press(Key.backspace)
    kbd.release(Key.backspace)

    kbd.type('Hi motherfucker!') #goes into the active app window

def on_press(key):
    if any ([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.add(key)
        if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
            execute()

def on_release(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.remove(key)

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

And the text is going to be in caps, because you're still going to be holding Shift the moment it's "typed".

Comment: Thank you. This does type exactly "HI MOTHERFUCKER!" when i am in the python window but when i take this to other windows the leading P does not go away. I will just change the keys for now.